# Path-relative style sheet import vulnerabilities

Tags: css, security

To avoid path-relative style sheet import vulnerabilities should I attach css file on my page using full path e.g.

```
<link href="http://mywebsite/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

instead of

```
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

What do you think?

Answer (score 8):

Just add a leading slash and make the path root-relative, rather than relative which this vulnerability relies on.
No need for the domain / scheme.

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/style.css">
```