# How to resolve path-relative stylesheet import (prssi) vulnerability fix on ASP.Net MVC legacy Application

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, qualys

We have a ASP.Net MVC 4, C# legacy internal application and recently when analyzing vulnerabilities on Production using Qualys Express scanner and we found below issue and recommends as well.

vulnerability  -: Path-relative stylesheet import (PRSSI)

Recommended solution -:It is recommended to remove relative URLs and use absolute URLs in CSS imports.

Could you help me what sort of change need to be done to resolve this. I have seen few options as below and we cant do major changes since this is a legacy application.

- Use X-Frame-Options and X-Content-Type-Options
- Set modern <!doctype html>
- Do not use relative paths
- [Path-relative style sheet import vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260013/path-relative-style-sheet-import-vulnerabilities)
- [https://forums.asp.net/t/2119720.aspx?Path+relative+style+sheet+import+vulnerabilities](https://forums.asp.net/t/2119720.aspx?Path%20relative%20style%20sheet%20import%20vulnerabilities)

And I dnt have capable to run the vulnerabilities report again so that's why im trying to findout best option resolve this for our application and do the entire change that needed if it is possible.