# How to resolve path relative stylesheet import vulnerabilities in Angular

Tags: angular

How to resolve path relative stylesheet import vulnerabilities in Angular.
In index.html, need to add a leading slash for css path and make the path root relative.

Current implementation,
link rel="stylesheet" *href="styles.css"
Need to add a '/' before the path.

Expected,
link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles.css"

Similar to
[Path-relative style sheet import vulnerabilities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29260013/path-relative-style-sheet-import-vulnerabilities)

Comment: Welcome to SO. I think you need to elaborate a bit in order to get a good answer to this question. Also showing some research effort (what you tried so far) might help.

Comment: I have to change a path in angular.json or some other config files. So that the path for css in index.html will be prefixed with a '/'. It should be href="/styles.css". This is to prevent path relative style import vulnerability.